# To Do list in HTML/Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make a to do list in Javascript / HTML5. Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To Do </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="todolist.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="To Do.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list"> 
   </div> 

        <form id="to_do_list">
        <h2>What do you want to do? </h2>

        <input type="text" id="task" name="task"><br>

        <br/>
        <button type="button" id="addToList"> Add to List </button> <br/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to work Javascript that will form a list with the user's entries. 
Sorry if this is easy, I am new to this.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () { 
    $("addToList").onclick = addTask; 
} 

var addTask = function() { 
    alert("You clicked it!"); 
}
```

Comment: What do you know so far?

Comment: I tried this, just to be able to control what happens when the button is clicked, but it doesn't work.`window.onload = function () 
 {
 $("addToList").onclick = addTask; 
 }

 var addTask = function() 
 { 
 alert("You clicked it!"); 
 }

} // end window.onload`

Comment: @EricaE I've added your comment to the question for visibility. In jQuery, you do not use the `onclick` attribute, you use the `on` handlers like this: `$('#addToList').on('click', addTask);`. Notice also the `#` symbol, which tells jQuery to use the ID of the element. In your current code, jQuery will look for a tag called `addToList` which does not exist.

Comment: A todo list app can be a large subject! It can be a good project to approach
several concepts. see some ideas: http://codepen.io/gaelb/pen/bdbMgL

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide whether to use JQuery or Javascript for your script section.

It looks you have used Javascript, then switched to JQuery to reference an object then went back to Javascript. Try to stick to just one.

```
<script>

// this could be $(window).ready(function() { ...

window.onload = function () { 
    $("#addToList").click(addTask); // you need to point at the id #addToList
} 

var addTask = function() { 
    var task = $("#task").val(); // references the value inside #task
    $("#list").append("<p>"+task+"</p>") // makes a new <p> element
    $("#task").val(""); // empties out #task
} 
</script>
```

I'm not really sure what you're looking for, but this does what I think you want.

Also, I don't think you should use spaces in filenames ("To do.js")